# Importing datasource and grafana dashboard while building container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, influxdb

I am trying to create docker containers with datasource and dashboard already preconfigured.
As of now I can understand that from v5.0 onwards grafana have introduced feature of provisioning.
I have created two yml file first the datasource and second the dashboard.
But I couldn't understand which part of docker-compose file will invoke these datasource.yml and dashboarad.yml file. What tag should I used and so on.Below are my docker-compose, datasource & dashboard file details.
Only detail in compose file I could bit understood is - `./grafana/provisioning/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/` which is copy some host folder structure to container (but not sure about it).

docker-compose.yml

```
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    links:
      - influxdb
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - 'grafana:/var/lib/grafana'
      - ./grafana/provisioning/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/
```

Dashboard.yml

```
apiVersion: 1

providers:
- name: 'Docker Dashboard'
  orgId: 1
  folder: ''
  type: file
  disableDeletion: false
  updateIntervalSeconds: 10 #how often Grafana will scan for changed dashboards
  options:
    path: <path-where-I-have-placed-jsonfile>
```

Datasource.yml

```
datasources:
-  access: 'proxy'                       # make grafana perform the requests
   editable: true                        # whether it should be editable
   is_default: true                      # whether this should be the default DS
   name: 'influx'                        # name of the datasource
   org_id: 1                             # id of the organization to tie this datasource to
   type: 'influxdb'                      # type of the data source
   url: 'http://<ip-address>:8086'       # url of the prom instance
   database: 'influx'
   version: 1                            # well, versioning
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `volumes` directive will run only in `runtime` not `build` you need to use `COPY` if you want that to work in `build` stage

Dockerfile:

```
FROM grafana/grafana
COPY ./grafana/provisioning /etc/grafana/provisioning
```

the `./grafana/provisioning` should be relative to `Dockerfile`

Compose:

```
grafana:
    build: .
    .
    .
```

Comment: should I COPY datasource.yml /etc/grafana/provisioning ? and same with dashboard ?

Comment: I have a single docker file which I was using for building influxdb image as well as grafana                                                                                                            
 FROM influxdb
COPY init.iql  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

FROM grafana/grafana
COPY datasource.yml /etc/grafana/provisioning
COPY dashboard.yml /etc/grafana/provisioning. Will it can cause problem?

Comment: you can not use a single dockerfile for the both , that will create multistage docker file , which I think you do not want to. I think you need to create two dockerfiles and manage them using compose

Comment: I have created two folder named grafana and influxdb and placed dockerfile inside them. Inside dockercompose file I have services:
  influxdb:
    build: . and services:
  grafana:
    build: . (folder name is grafana and influxdb? I guess that is the correct way)

Comment: yes, in compose use `context: .`and `dockerfile: grafana/Dockerfile` under `build`directive

Comment: while running docker-compose up ---->  lvl=eror msg="can't read datasource provisioning files from directory" logger=provisioning.datasources path=/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources error="open /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources: no such file or directory"

Comment: did you remove the volumes section from your compose? seems not

Comment: I am able to import single datasource and dashboard. If I want to have more than one datasources and more than one dashboard.Then for dashboard I have copied the file in /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards. But how do we define more than one datasource

Comment: you should open a new question regarding grafana configs.